# Repair superficial damage to a carbon frame

Tags: repair, carbon, seatpost, damage

I have a [carbon frame](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-us/bikes/model/tcr.advanced.sl.isp.frameset.black/9005/51138/) with an integrated seatpost. The saddle sits on a clamp that is meant to secure the saddle on the seatpost and NOT hold the weight of the rider too. I went on a ride and my knees started to bother me, so I went to adjust the height of the saddle and after reading the torque number for the binder clamp, realized I was shit out of luck and was going to either raise the saddle and risk damaging the carbon fiber or let it be and hurt my knees more.  I of course chose to raise my saddle. So now I have some nasty gouges where the clamp rubbed the length of the seatpost.

I have spacers in place now to raise the saddle to the correct height but now I have some ugly scratches that are visible just below the binder clamp.

So, the question is, what should I use to keep the surface carbon from cracking more and to seal it up?  I have been told to use either paint(not sure what kind) and to use a clear nail polish. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have repaired non structural and surface carbon blemishes with clear nail polish. I had no issues and used the handle bars for several years with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

I've been advised by my local supplier of carbon fibre to use a polyurethane paint to finish carbon fibre. You can buy it in spray cans from a paint or hardware shop.

Don't use paint stripper because that will damage the epoxy resin used to bind the carbon fibre.